# How to handle shared dependencies when sharing components between multiple applications in a monorepo

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, webpack-4, styled-components

I've got the following monorepo structure

```
root
--AppOne
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components

--AppTwo
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components

--Shared
----componentA
----package.json
----node_modules
------styled-components
```

My issue is that both AppOne and AppTwo are using a `componentA` from the `shared` directory, and it depends on an NPM package, for example on `styled-components`

This means that I need to have `styled-components` installed in all three directories, and this increases the bundle size and if the versions aren't the same can cause issues with the package doing what it is supposed to do.

It also means I get the following error from `styled-components`:

`It looks like there are several instances of 'styled-components' initialized in this application.
This may cause dynamic styles not rendering properly, errors happening during rehydration process and makes your application bigger without a good reason.`

My question is - what is the best way to solve this situation? Ideally I only want this package installed in one place. Should I be installing it in `Shared` and using an alias in `AppOne` and `AppTwo` to use the package?

Any advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Working on a big monorepo myself, I will say that there are many ways to solve this by writing custom scripts, and trigger them on npm "post-install". Probably you can also manually maintain this relationship between dependencies in each of the package.json's peerDependencies.

I prefer to rely on tooling to handle inter-dependency management.
In my project, I use Lerna which has a [package hoisting feature](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md) exactly for this use case.
If Lerna is overkill for you, you should know that package hoisting is also provided by [Yarn Workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). In fact, when Lerna is used on top of Yarn, Lerna simply delegates the package hoisting to Yarn Workspaces, so you really don't need Lerna for that.

I also heard of [Bolt](https://github.com/boltpkg/bolt) in this regard, but as of early 2019 it's very promising but much less mature than Yarn/Lerna.